# Formatting Dates and Times in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01830

I'm working with Oracle and I'm using SQL Developer-1.5.4.59.40 but I have a problem.  I don't know how  use the format for date.  I want to use a format: "dd/mm/aaaa hh24:mm" but Oracle doesn't accept it.  Tthe error is:

ORA-01830: La máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena de entrada

Answer (score 1):

try "DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI"

some blind text to make the answer long enough

Answer (score 1):

to change the date format for all queries (and have it remembered day to day)

in SQL Deverloper:

1. Goto Tools
2. Preferences
3. Database
4. NLS
5. and change Date Format to "DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI" (as suggested by Jens)

now to simply do that in a query

```
SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') 
  FROM DUAL ;

  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYYHH24:MI') 
------------------------------------ 
04/01/2011 16:08
```

Comment: uhmm  also use jsp for aplication

Comment: @user563062, sorry jsp was not mentioned in the original question, you can use parameters to handle the date casting into the package/procedures you are using, a simple google search yields several examples of how to do this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetdatefromOracle.htm and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

If `some_date` is the column name of date type then you can use the `to_char` function to convert to any format.

```
select to_char(some_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
to_date(some_date,'dd/mm/yyyyhh24:mi:ss')
```

Where `some_date` is for example '31/08/2012'.